# plotting proportions with geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-ribbon

I'm trying to show how changes in the proportions of different age classes have changed through time. Presently, for all the data, I have the proportion of individuals at a given age (pAge), and cumulative sums of the proportions that provide the min/max values for each age (cpAgeMin and cpAgeMax) that I'm using in geom_ribbon.

Unfortunately, even though all the proportions sum to 1, my plot doesn't seem to properly reflect the data as there are open spots without data in several years. These don't seem to be issues with the data, but rather something ggplot is doing.  How do I fix this so that the entire area from 0-1 in every year is assigned to one age class.

```
# subset of data
df <- structure(list(site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                  levels = "G", class = "factor"), 
                 year = c(1988, 1988, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 
                          1992, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1999, 
                          1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 
                          2003, 2003, 2003), 
                 age = c(`9104` = 1, `9341` = 2, `9292` = 1, `9632` = 2, `9960` = 4, 
                         `9543` = 1, `9857` = 3, `9685` = 1, `9968` = 2, `10169` = 3, 
                         `9858` = 1, `10127` = 2, `10212` = 3, `10009` = 1, `10284` = 2, 
                         `10522` = 6, `10464` = 1, `10605` = 2, `10830` = 3, `10556` = 1, 
                         `10744` = 2, `11056` = 3, `10687` = 1, `11061` = 2, `11279` = 5, 
                         `10912` = 1, `11109` = 2, `11197` = 3, `11065` = 1, `11194` = 2, 
                         `11154` = 1, `11255` = 2, `11324` = 3), 
                 pAGE = c(0.972, 0.028, 0.964, 0.005, 0.031, 0.823, 0.177, 0.921, 0.074, 
                          0.004, 0.846, 0.045, 0.109, 0.833, 0.155, 0.012, 0.927, 0.054, 
                          0.019, 0.784, 0.21, 0.005, 0.958, 0.017, 0.025, 0.852, 0.124, 
                          0.024, 0.913, 0.087, 0.909, 0.073, 0.019), 
                 cpAgeMin = c(0, 0.972, 0, 0.964, 0.969, 0, 0.823, 0, 0.921, 0.996, 0, 
                              0.846, 0.891, 0, 0.833, 0.988, 0, 0.927, 0.981, 0, 0.784, 
                              0.995, 0, 0.958, 0.975, 0, 0.852, 0.976, 0, 0.913, 0, 0.909, 
                              0.981), 
                 cpAgeMax = c(0.972, 1, 0.964, 0.969, 1, 0.823, 1, 0.921, 0.996, 1, 0.846, 
                              0.891, 1, 0.833, 0.988, 1, 0.927, 0.981, 1, 0.784, 0.995, 1, 
                              0.958, 0.975, 1, 0.852, 0.976, 1, 0.913, 1, 0.909, 0.981, 1),
                 seg = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                         2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), 
            row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# plot
ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = year, ymin = cpAgeMin, ymax = cpAgeMax, group = interaction(seg, factor(age)), fill = factor(age), col = factor(age))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

After implementing @Andy Baxter's solution to a second site, there are extra "bumps" outside of the range of the data that appear in the plot. How do I get rid of these?

[image]

Comment: Is there missing data? For example for age == 1, there is no information for years 1994 to 1998 inclusive. Is that expected?

Comment: Yeah, `ggplot` really isn't liking your implicit missing values (e.g. no entry for age=2 in 1990) and is just drawing across them. You'll have to convert those from implicit into explicit (probably by using `complete` and `fill`)

Comment: @Peter, I forgot in my initial question to add the seg parameter which identifies the continuous periods of monitoring. This leaves a gap in the years without data. Unfortunately, it does not address the issues in the early and late years when ggplot has white areas that shouldn't be present.

Comment: @Dubukay, I've tweaked the question above to address this issue, but unfortunately it doesn't address the white areas where there is existing data.

Comment: Check `cpAgeMin` for `age` == 2 and `year` == 1990. should this  be the same as for  `cpAgeMax` for  `age` == 1 and `year` == 1990?

Comment: @Peter, there is not an age == 2 for 1990, but age 1 has a min = 0 and a max 0.97 and age 3 has a min = 0.97 and a max = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacking it with `geom_area` and `position = "fill"` might be smoothest:

```r
library(tidyverse)


df |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_area(
    aes(
    x = year,
    y = pAGE,
    group = interaction(seg, factor(age)),
    fill = factor(age)
    ),
    position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)  # to get right order
  )
```

[image]

Comment: this is great and so much simpler. However, when I add in other sites, it seems to add in some extra data outside of the range of my dataset. I'll add an image into my question.  Do you know what's causing that issue?

Comment: That's very odd! I was trying to clean spots off my screen for a second but the bumps up and down the sides remain. I would suggest removing the `colour` aspect from `aes` or ensuring `colour = NULL` to not draw lines and see if it's just an artefact of plotting many complex polygons?

Comment: indeed after some playing with `colour = "black", linewidth = 5` _outside_ of the `aes` call it seems to add in the line-ends sticking out of the plotting area. Suggest you remove `colour = factor(age)` from your code which should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Eeesh, okay I don't love this solution but here's something that works to fill in the missing values. Basically we need to use `complete` to turn the implicit NAs into explicit NAs, but then we need to fill things in in a "zig-zag" fashion instead of straight down a column. There's probably a better way of doing this but here's what I came up with:

```r
df %>%
  complete(year, age) %>%
  mutate(cpAgeMin=ifelse(is.na(cpAgeMin), lag(cpAgeMax), cpAgeMin)) %>%
  mutate(cpAgeMax=ifelse(is.na(cpAgeMax), cpAgeMin, cpAgeMax)) %>%
  mutate(cpAgeMin=ifelse(is.na(cpAgeMin), lag(cpAgeMax), cpAgeMin)) %>%
  mutate(cpAgeMax=ifelse(is.na(cpAgeMax), cpAgeMin, cpAgeMax)) %>%
  mutate(cpAgeMin=ifelse(is.na(cpAgeMin), lag(cpAgeMax), cpAgeMin)) %>%
  mutate(cpAgeMax=ifelse(is.na(cpAgeMax), cpAgeMin, cpAgeMax)) %>%
  mutate(cpAgeMin=ifelse(is.na(cpAgeMin), lag(cpAgeMax), cpAgeMin)) %>%
  mutate(cpAgeMax=ifelse(is.na(cpAgeMax), cpAgeMin, cpAgeMax)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = year, ymin = cpAgeMin, ymax = cpAgeMax, group = factor(age), fill = factor(age), col = factor(age))) +
  theme_bw()
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: thanks for this! Definitely looks a lot better than the initial plot. But I can't connect the lines across the gap in years where I don't have any data (1994-1997). Maybe this would work if the complete also included seg somehow?

Comment: `+facet_wrap(~seg, nrow=1, scales="free_x")`

Comment: Otherwise you can manually fill those years in with NAs which will break the ribbon or pass them as two separate calls to geom_ribbon

Comment: Thanks. Faceting is not an option, but I'll fiddle around with NA values.

Comment: Do you know how to get complete to only complete within each seg? I find the documentation around complete to be very confusing.